# What is the best way to unit test a Windows CE / .NET CF app?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-ce

I want to write unit tests for an app running on Windows CE .NET Compact Framework 3.5. Ideally I'd like to deploy them and run them on the device rather than emulated for true testing but if it could also run locally in Visual Studio for speed that would be great. I am mostly writing console apps and don't care about a nice gui but it would be nice.

I tried csUnit but it had dependencies on libraries that aren't part of CF and my device didn't have room for them anyway.

Has anyone had found a quick simply test framework they'd recommend?

Comment: Do you wish to test your business layer or your UI? Testing BL on your desktop should be sufficient. You can recompile your code using a Class Library project and write unit code for the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio Team System 2008 with Test Edition or Team Suite, you can use the built-in device unit testing.

[Walkthrough: Creating and Running a Smart Device Unit Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384146.aspx)

[Unit testing .Net Compact Framework applications with Visual Studio 2008](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/vs2008/6222)

Comment: According to the SO question, not really: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004560/rhino-mocks-compact-framework. => "The key is to make stub classes instead of Mock classes "