# Debug COM Component in Windows CE

Tags: visual-studio, com, asp-classic, vbscript, windows-ce

We have developed a COM component to be used in ASP pages of HTTPD service in Windows CE. We need to debug the COM Component. We have limited active sync capability with `ConmanClient2.exe` and `cMaccept.exe`.
What should we do debug the component from our PCs?
Where can we get more information on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the Visual Studio native code debugger to the [services.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms938094.aspx) process. This process will be the one loading your COM dll. For more information you can read the native code part of [this page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228818%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (Walkthrough: Debugging a Solution that Includes Both Managed and Native Code).

Comment: Should I copy the pdb files to the WINCE device?

Comment: No need, Visual Studio will take those from your development desktop. You can select them manually if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to define an interface contract of your COM components. Write a [unit tester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684583/what-is-the-best-way-to-unit-test-a-windows-ce-net-cf-app) that tests your contract. When the unit tester is a normal Windows CE program, you can debug it along with the testee `COM component`.

*Edit:* I would discourage from debugging any module in services. Which test environment is used is not important but it should isolate the module.

Comment: The link you posted proposes using .NetCF. This could be a good idea if the specific OS image being used provides .NetCF, unfortunately this is not always the case.